# How to set selenoid address in selenoid ui via configuration manager

Tags: selenoid

I have selenoid running on port 4450. I need to setup selenoid ui with port of selenoid set to 4450 via configuration manager. How can I do this ?

Tried the following but did not work

```
cm.exe selenoid-ui start --args "--selenoid-uri http://localhost:4450"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CM tool only delivers very standard configuration of Selenoid and Selenoid UI using standard ports like 8080 and 4444. If you need anything custom - you have to start everything yourself with `docker run`.